# No space on 8gb usb stick shows 100% du shows 3.5mb

Tags: python, linux, debian, fsck

```
root@rasp:/home/pi# df
df: `/squashfs': No such file or directory
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs           7498344 7481956         0 100% /
dev               116816       0    116816   0% /dev
/dev/sda1        7498344 7481956         0 100% /mnt
none             7498344 7481956         0 100% /
tmpfs              47560    1360     46200   3% /run
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs              95100       0     95100   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1   1920672   32128   1888544   2% /media/1235-BBEA
root@rasp:/home/pi#

root@rasp:/home/pi#ls|xargs du -s
4       a
5133    bin
20016   boot
19956   boot.bak
384     current.cache
0       dev
3622    etc
11673   home
282159  lib
0       lost+found
32164   media
8       mnt
45560   opt
du: cannot access `proc/23878/task/23878/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/23878/task/23878/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/23878/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/23878/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0       proc
110489  root
1360    run
7795    sbin
0       selinux
0       srv
0       sys
80      tmp
1619487 usr
128080  var
12      webmin-setup.out

du -sh
3.6M    .
```

Had webmin installed and python2.7 and then installed python3.4.
Doing a webmin update failed as it needed 2.7.
Since then disk shows full.Somewhere there is a large
file about 5GB hidden and using all the suggestions in other posts
didn't work.The rpi is 3500 miles away so its a bit hard to work with.
Sounds like I need to go to single user mode and fsck the /dev/sda1
which should happen on a reboot. After spending 3 days on this have run
out of ideas. This probably is more of a Debian/linux question.

Comment: Try removing everything in /var/cache/apt/archives to free up some space so you can investigate properly.  E.g. try for i in a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z; do sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/$i*; done

Comment: Running those `du` figures up in a spreadsheet and removing the one for `/media` as it is a separate partition suggests that around 2.3GB is used for the root partition - but that is claiming that 7.4M 1K blocks are used.  I must confess I am a little confused but it does look as though something is seriously amiss.  And, as it is the super user running the du command you do not have the (default) 5% reserved (for the super-user) space left as headroom to sort things out with.  Joan's suggestion to clear out the /var/apt/cache/archive of *.deb files will give you a little space to work in...

Comment: only 320k in the cache only 125M total in /var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recall coming across a similar situation where a process was holding a file descriptor on a deleted file. Thus, the space could not be freed unless the offending process closed that handle. 
Try grepping /proc//fd for clues.
What is process 23878 doing? Is it perhaps logging to a rotated logfile?

Comment: That process is probably the initial `ls` that has terminated by the time the `du` command gets to consider the output from it - I do not think it is going to be the problem here (if the commands are repeated you would get a similar reports about a different, short-lived process).

Answer (score 2):

You haven't expanded your filesystem. Execute the command shown below when signed into the user 'pi':

```
sudo raspi-config
```

When shown with a screen, choose Option 1, to expand your filesystem. Press the enter key when highlighting over the option. This should make you be able to use more space on your Pi.

I don't know what to do about your distance situation but this is what I can suggest for you freeing up space.

Comment: /dev/mmcblk0p1 is a 2gb sd with bootloader /dev/sda1 is an 8gb usb stick both at max.raspi-config looks for /dev/root and cant find it so wont expand anyway

Comment: what do you mean grep /proc//fd ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it

killed X and apache2

created a forcefsck in /
touch /forcefsck
then forced a reboot

echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
this did a reboot and the fsck must have cleaned up the drive.
back to normal now

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs           7498344 2804224   4290180  40% /
dev               116816       0    116816   0% /dev
/dev/sda1        7498344 2804224   4290180  40% /mnt
none             7498344 2804224   4290180  40% /
tmpfs              47560    1220     46340   3% /run
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs              95100       0     95100   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1   1920672   32128   1888544   2% /media/1235-BBEA
```

thanks

Comment: In some cases an open file in /tmp may not appear but still uses disk space.  If you can find the application that's using it and kill it that usually clears it up - or rebooting.  `lsof` might be help in this case to point to the file in use and what's opening it.